# Angular ngclass else condition

Tags: angular

I am using ng-class and its working fine. I have hardcoded some ids but i need to know how can i add else condition in this.

I am doing like this

```
[ngClass]="{'theme-bg2' : x.programId ==  2 || x.programId ==  9 || x.programId ==  10, 'bg-c-blue' : x.programId ==  4 || x.programId ==  5, 'theme-bg' : x.programId ==  6 || x.programId ==  3}"
```

I try like this but not working

```
[ngClass]="{'theme-bg2' : x.programId ==  2 || x.programId ==  9 || x.programId ==  10, 'bg-c-blue' : x.programId ==  4 || x.programId ==  5, 'theme-bg' : x.programId ==  6 || x.programId ==  3, theme-bg}"
```

Comment: You can use regular `class` to add a default styling, then use your `ngClass` classes to modify that styling. So if the `x.programId` doesn't match any of the used Ids, it will just stay on `class` styling.

Comment: @MishaMashina I have try this but its not working.

Comment: @rameezkhan How about `[ngClass]="{..., theme-bg: true}"`?

Comment: @rameezkhan I think it does work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfxwfh I've added `!important` only to handle more vars being `true`, but in your example only one `programId` clause can be true.

Comment: Better to use function, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngClass in the way `[ngClass]="exprexion"`. in this case the "expresion should be a ternary expresion concatenated

```
[ngClass]="
     x.programId ==  2 || x.programId ==  9 || x.programId ==  10?'theme-bg2' :
     x.programId ==  4 || x.programId ==  5 ? 'bg-c-blue' :
     x.programId ==  6 || x.programId ==  3 ? 'theme-bg' : 
     theme-bg"
```